# what is difference between android noHistory and android FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TASK

Tags: android

when to use android :noHistory and when to use Intent FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TASK?
in my scenario I want to clear backstack which contains activity A when I want to travel from Activity B to Activity C? so should I use noHistory or FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TASK?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the Android developer docs:

[`FLAG_ACTIVITY_NO_HISTORY`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html#FLAG_ACTIVITY_NO_HISTORY)

> If set, the new activity is not kept in the history stack. As soon as the user navigates away from it, the activity is finished. This may also be set with the [`noHistory`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/R.styleable.html#AndroidManifestActivity_noHistory) attribute.

[`FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TASK`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html#FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TASK), however, performs a different role:

> If set in an Intent passed to Context.startActivity(), this flag will cause any existing task that would be associated with the activity to be cleared before the activity is started. That is, the activity becomes the new root of an otherwise empty task, and any old activities are finished. This can only be used in conjunction with FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK.

In summary, using `FLAG_ACTIVITY_NO_HISTORY` or `noHistory` will ensure that the new activity is not added to the history stack (therby skipping it when popping off subsequent views), whereas `FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TASK` will cause any existing task that would be associated with the activity to be cleared before the activity is started.

So in your use case, you want to use `FLAG_ACTIVITY_NO_HISTORY` with Activity A, which will ensure that it is not added to the back stack.